# Mongodb - add if not exists (non id field)

Tags: mongodb

I have a large number of records to iterate over (coming from an external data source) and then insert into a mongo db.

I do not want to allow duplicates.  How can this be done in a way that will not affect performance.

The number of records is around 2 million.

Comment: Create an unique index. This will have a slight impact on write performance but might speed up reads (depends on your read patterns).

Comment: Good advice has been given in comments and in other comments ( posing as answers ) but there is no real clarification here of what you are actually doing to justify a real answer. Please add some information to you question to explain what exactly you consider to be a "duplicate" you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two fairly straightforward ways to do this in mongodb, although a lot depends upon your use case.

One, you can use the upsert:true option to update, using whatever you define as your unique key as the query for the update. If it does not exist it will insert it, otherwise it will update it.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Two, you could just create a unique index on that key and then insert ignoring the error generated. Exactly how to do this will be somewhat dependent on language and driver used along with version of mongodb. This has the potential to be faster when performing batch inserts, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

2 million is not a huge number that will affect performance, split your records fields into diffent collections will be good enough.

i suggest create a unique index on your unique key before insert into the mongodb.
unique index will filter redundant data and lose some records and you can ignore the error.